# ASP.NET Web Forms Event handler modifies page component after loading

Tags: asp.net, webforms, event-handling, pageload

I am showing a loading image until page load completes and I want to show this image again until button click event handler completes. But due to page life cycle in asp.NET web forms, I can't achieve this. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Hi are you using asp.net forms or mvc . Also your button click is ajax call ?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Web Forms

Comment: So it should be when you click on but set the visibility of the image container to true and at the end when of click set it to false

Comment: I added an answer please try . i also pasted the link from where I took the idea . Please have a look hope it will help . Please mind that there are other ways like jquery to show and hide the progress where you can use  $post method to do this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option is to use update panel although you can achieve this by jquery also . In updated panel you can have a div with the loading indicator and then this will show up when you click on the button please try .

The credit goes to this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Loading-Progress-Indicator-using-GIF-Image-when-UpdatePanel-is-updating-in-ASPNet.aspx

```
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="center">
                    <img alt="" src="loader.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div align="center">
                <h1>
                    Click the button to see the UpdateProgress!</h1>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

//  css

```
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: Black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
}
.center
{
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 300px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: White;
    border-radius: 10px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
}
.center img
{
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @SafaaMamdouhSalem great to hear that . please accept my answer